# QGIS display menu settings

Tags: qgis

I have a laptop with resolution 3840x2160 and qgis is displayed well. Additionally, I use a bigger screen with resolution 1920x1080. The menu of QGIS 3.18.3 is not correctly adapted here. The buttons are very big and the text is very small and not readably.[image] How can I adapt this?

Answer (score 2):

You can change it from:

Settings> Options> General> Font> Size:

[image]

You will need to restart QGIS for the changes to take place.

Comment: when using two screens you have to change the settings all the time and it do not adapt automatically. Additionally, the settings do not fix the window, only the font size. Maybe it is something to be developed?